# What is <fieldsets> in Magento Config.xml

Tags: magento

What is the  `<fieldsets>` tags do in config.xml ? Could you please explain me about fieldset in core config file and custom module config file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `<fieldsets>`* tag is usually only found in `config.xml` files.

The `<fieldsets>` tag is mainly used to define which fields (attributes) are to be copied to where while converting objects, e.g. in a `quote` to `order` conversion.

Excerpt of `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <!-- : -->
    <global>
        <!-- : -->
        <fieldsets>
            <!-- : -->
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <remote_ip>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </remote_ip>
                <x_forwarded_for>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </x_forwarded_for>
                <customer_id>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_id>
                <customer_email>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_email>
                <!-- : -->
                <items_qty>
                    <to_order>total_qty_ordered</to_order>
                </items_qty>
            </sales_convert_quote>
            <!-- : -->
        </fieldsets>
        <!-- : -->
    </global>
    <!-- : -->
</config>
```

Furthermore, the `<fieldsets>` tag is used to define the fields which are to be parsed/converted while importing/exporting products or customers via Magento Dataflow.

Edit:

> `<fieldsets>` automatically transport the data's from one table to another table ?

No. They just define *what* is to be copied to *where* for a specific aspect.

Scan the Magento source for `Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset()` occurrences to see how the real copy processes look like.

For customer/product dataflows scan for `Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset()` calls, respectively.

---

<sub>* Note the trailing `s` in `<fieldsets>`. This is **not** about the HTML `<fieldset>` tag.</sub>

Comment: <fieldsets> automatically transport the data's from one table to another table ?